# Is there any way to create async methods in Interface for Repository layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, repository-pattern

How would I create an interface for the repository code? It says, the Interface should not have async methods inside. and In Repository, It says, Interface methods are not implemented.

can anyone post code for the repository interface(I mean, code for ISampleRepository which is in asp.net core MVC has repository layer which has async action methods), In which method declared interface as async methods?

Comment: You don't declare them as async in your interfaace, just as a `Task`. I.E. `public interface MyInterface { Task<MyResult> SomeTaskAsync(MyTaskParameters model); }`. You can then mark it as `async` in your implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer #nbokmans, It's working. Adding Task action to return types without Async method.